# Who confers the title "Goswami"?

Tags: title

Just like there are some known conditions to be satisfied for being a *sanyasi*, *paramahamsa*, etc., are there some checklists of requirements to be completed, for someone to be called  a "Goswami"? Like - Goswami Tulsidãsa.

Or Is it just a surname with no religious connotations found in the scriptures?

Comment: thanks for the edit @vivikta